# problem sending varibles to remote url with CURL

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl

I'm trying to send variables from server A to server B, and back. I have everything working other then actually sending the variables from server A to server B. So i can send variables back from server B to server A but just cant send them to Server B from server A. I use JSON to send the variables back (which works fine) and i use `_POST` to send them to server B.

Here is my code on both Servers:

**Server A**

```
<?

require ('../refference.php');

$post_fields = array(
    'unq__id' => $sponsor_reference,
    'gdi__username' => $sponsor_GDI_id,
);
$ch = curl_init('http://site.com/WP/d__access.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$data = json_decode($result);

$sponsor_first_nme = $data->sponsor_first_nme;


echo $sponsor_first_nme;


?>
```

**Server B**

```
<?

include ('config/wp__2135432135435135412312415456654452547534.php');

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$reference = $_POST['unq__id'];
$username = $_POST['gdi__username'];
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE ". "GDI_Username = '$username' AND Unique_id = '$reference'");

while($check = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $sponsor_email = $check["Email"];
    $sponsor = $check["GDI_Username"];
    $sponsor_first_nme = $check["First_Name"];
    $sponsor_second_nme = $check["Last_Name"];
    $sponsor_domain = $check["GDI_Domain"];
    $unq_id = $check["Unique_id"];
 } 

$sponsor_name = "$sponsor_first_nme $sponsor_second_nme";

$result = array(
    'sponsor_first_nme' => $sponsor_first_nme, 
    'sponsor_second_nme' => $sponsor_second_nme, 
    'sponsor_email' => $sponsor_email,
    'sponsor' => $sponsor,
    'sponsor_domain' => $sponsor_domain,
    'unq_i' => $unq_id,
    'sponsor_full_name' => $sponsor_name,
);

echo json_encode($result);



?>
```

I know that everything else works fine as I've replaced:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE ". "GDI_Username = '$username' AND Unique_id = '$reference'");
```

WITH

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE ". "GDI_Username = 'myusername' AND Unique_id = '45415645154'");
```

So i know the problem lies within sending the variables (

```
'unq__id' => $sponsor_reference,
        'gdi__username' => $sponsor_GDI_id,
```

from server A as i cant use them in the script on server B)

When i test it using the variables, I just get a blank page, but when i replace that line as mentioned above, i get the name ($sponsor_first_nme) echoed out (the expected result)

Comment: try sending the variables as a string not an array

Comment: hey, How would i do that? Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below @nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working, well it seemed to be working the whole time...

I was just echoing it out incorrectly. I used `echo $sponsor_first_nme` when it was supposed to be `echo "$sponsor_first_nme"` (with quotes).

Really appreciate all your help though! Thanks a BUNCH!

Answer (score 0):

Send the post data as a string

```
$fields = array(
    'unq__id' => $sponsor_reference,
    'gdi__username' => $sponsor_GDI_id,
);

$field_string = "";
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
   $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string,'&');
```

Now you can send it in curl:

**Edit:**

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. It's still doing the same thing (blank page, not echoing out the data)

Comment: Hey, still lost here. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @nav: not really sure what the problem. Try to var_dump($_POST). also are you using this in wordpress? if so it will not work this way

Comment: hello. It's okay, I've got it working. It seemed to be working the whole time, i was just echoing it out incorrectly. I used "echo $sponsor_first_nme" when it was supposed to be "echo "$sponsor_first_nme" (with quotes). Thanks fr all your help though. Really appreciated. Also, why wouldn't it work with WordPress? It's working now, and I'm using WordPress...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**serialize()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to create a string representation of whatever you are trying to send.

Comment: hey, could you explain how i would go about this option? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the post option before you set the post data.

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $post_fields);
```

If not, the post data could be empty.

Comment: hey. The data is not empty. I just tried what you suggested. no luck. Thanks